# Unable to debug - failed to use stack

Tags: c, debugging, data-structures, stack

I used a stack to do something with characters like the code below.
When I run this program it doesn't print anything on sceen. I have tried to debug but it has error "program received signal SIGTRAP, trace/breakpoint trap".Please help. Tks for your help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
short IsEmpty(int *top){
    if (*top==-1) return 1;
    return 0;
}
short IsFull(int *top, int capacity){
    if (*top == capacity) return 1;
    return 0;
}
void Push(int *top, int capacity, char *stack, char value){
    if (IsFull(top, capacity)==1) printf("stack overflow");
    else{
        ++*top;
        stack[*top]=value;
    }
}
void Pop(int *top, int capacity, char *stack){
    if (IsEmpty(top)==1) printf("stack underflow");
    else{
        free(stack[*top]);
        --*top;
    }
}

int main(){
    int top=-1;
    int capacity;
    printf("import capacity of stack: "); scanf("%d",&capacity);
    char *stack=(char *)malloc(capacity*sizeof(char));
    Push(&top, capacity, stack, 'A');
    Push(&top, capacity, stack, 'B');
    Push(&top, capacity, stack, 'C');
    Pop(&top, capacity, stack);
    Pop(&top, capacity, stack);
    Push(&top, capacity, stack, 'D');
    printf("%s",stack[1]);
    free(stack);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: place breakpoint at main the try to run. You have serious UB in your code so if the debugger starts the execution you will end up in the segfault         free(stack[*top]);

Comment: @P__J__ I use free(stack[*top]) because I want to remove the value of stack[*top]. Now I know it is wrong. So how can I remove the its value completely?

Answer (score 1):

If you find you are unable to debug, you should do two things:

1. Check you are able to debug other, existing programs in your environment. This will rule out an issue with the environment rather than the code in question.
2. Comment out all except a very few lines of your program so that it will run. Then, selectively uncomment lines until you isolate the problem to a particular line.

Having isolated the problem to one line, you can then do an internet search on the particular issue.

Comment: I will try to do that. tks for your help